# How to use htaccess to redirect multiple files

Tags: redirect, expression

I want to redirect any file that begins with the letters "cross" from the root to a subfolder e.g

domain.com/cross001.html should redirect to domain.com/subfolder/cross01.html and

domain.com/cross077.php should redirect to domain.com/subfolder/cross077.php

I have looked at multiple redirect examples but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've tried variations of:

`redirectmatch ^cross* /subfolder/cross*`

but cannot work out what is the correct way to structure this redirect